# Capacitor Google Map not working correctly on device for Vue3

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, vuejs3, capacitor

I am having a ton of trouble with @capacitor/google-maps working on Vue. When I run in web it all works fine:

[image]

I am using the base example:

```
<capacitor-google-map id="map"></capacitor-google-map>
<button @click="createMap()">Create Map</button>

<style>
  capacitor-google-map {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 275px;
    height: 400px;
  }
</style>

<script>
 import { GoogleMap } from '@capacitor/google-maps';

   const createMap = async () => {
   const mapRef = document.getElementById('map');

    const newMap = await GoogleMap.create({
     id: 'my-map', // Unique identifier for this map instance
     element: mapRef, // reference to the capacitor-google-map element
     apiKey: '####-#####-#####', // Your Google Maps API Key
       config: {
        center: {
          // The initial position to be rendered by the map
           lat: 33.6,
           lng: -117.9,
       },
      zoom: 8, // The initial zoom level to be rendered by the map
     },
    });
   };


 </script>

await newMap.addMarker({
    coordinate: {
        lat: 33.6,
        lng: -117.9
    }
});

// Handle marker click
    await newMap.setOnMarkerClickListener((_event: any) => {
        alert('clicked');
    });
```

And it renders this on my iphone, I don't see any of the map details at all and when I click on the marker the map disappears.  Ionic does not have any documentation for this plugin with Vue and I'm wondering if I am missing something?

[image]

Comment: Ok so I found out what what going on. I initially just used the Javascript Api in Google Console but then went back and added ios Sdk and Android Sdk BUT I used the same key and google was failing. I deleted my key and created a new one then it started working.

Comment: Did you register capacitor-google-map component in any place? i have the same problem